# Duplicate entries using ASP.NET MVC 4, Entity Framework & SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, duplicates

I inherited an ASP.NET MVC 4 app that is using Entity Framework and keep getting duplicate records on related tables. I haven't been able to figure out why this is happening and it only happens randomly.

The models are as such:

- `Company` -> has many `Users` -> has many `UserRoles`
- `UserRoles` references the `Roles` table which has a `RoleId` and `Name`.

It is duplicating entries in the `Roles` table. I have been trying to figure this out but am pretty new with EF and some of that.

`UserRole.cs` partial class:

```
public static bool UpdateUserRoles(int userId, List<int> roleIds) 
{
        using (var context = new ImageTrackerEntities()) 
        {
            var userRoles = context.UserRoles.Where(r => r.UserId == userId).ToList();

            foreach (var role in userRoles)
            {
                // do not remove users from super admin role
                context.Entry(role).State = EntityState.Deleted;
            }

            foreach (var id in roleIds) 
            {
                var ur = new UserRole() {
                    RoleId = id,
                    UserId = userId
                };

                context.Entry(ur).State = EntityState.Added;
            }

            context.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you show the code where user roles are assigned? Does that happen in multiple places in the database? You could prevent it from happening by adding a unique constraint on the roles table.

Comment: Have you found anything by debugging it?

Comment: I can't get it to happen usually, but in production is it happening more and more often.

Comment: Is there any pattern to it?

Comment: Is this the only place where roles are modified? Also, is there anywhere you can rename/edit a role?

Comment: Yea this should be the only place, and no you can't rename or edit a role.

Answer (score 0):

To notice whats happened more precisely , try to activate EF Log so you can see the SQL generated (If you are using EF6 (current version of course)). Something like this :

```
using (var context = new BlogContext()) 
{ 
    //YOU NEED TO ADD THIS
    context.Database.Log = Console.Write; 

    var blog = context.Blogs.First(b => b.Title == "One Unicorn"); 

    blog.Posts.First().Title = "Green Eggs and Ham"; 

    blog.Posts.Add(new Post { Title = "I do not like them!" }); 

    context.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

This will generate the following output:

```
SELECT TOP (1)
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
    [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title]
    FROM [dbo].[Blogs] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE (N'One Unicorn' = [Extent1].[Title]) AND ([Extent1].[Title] IS NOT NULL)
-- Executing at 7/17/2015 10:55:41 AM -07:00
-- Completed in 4 ms with result: SqlDataReader
```